# PyQt Round Spalsh Screens Corners

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 splash screen. What I'm trying to do is round the corners of the splash screen itself. However, when I try `splash.setStyleSheet(u"border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px;")`, it adds a rounded border to the widgets INSIDE the splash screen and not the splash screen itself. How could I round the corners.

This is the code for my splash screen:

```py
splash_pix = QtGui.QPixmap('con.png')

splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(splash_pix, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
splash.resize(700, 700)
splash.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71); border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px;")
qtRectangle = splash.frameGeometry()
centerPoint = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
splash.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())
# adding progress bar
progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(splash)
progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 390, 571, 23))
progressBar.setStyleSheet(u"QProgressBar{\n"
"\n"
"background-color: rgb(98, 114, 164);\n"
"color: rgb(200, 200, 200);\n"
"border-style: none;\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QProgressBar::chunk{\n"
"\n"
"   border-radius: 10px;\n"
"   background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0.943182, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(254, 121, 199, 255), stop:1 rgba(170, 85, 255, 255));\n"
"}")


lodingLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(splash)

loding_font = QFont()
loding_font.setPointSize(14)
loding_font.setFamily(u"Franklin Gothic Medium")

lodingLbl.setFont(loding_font)
lodingLbl.setStyleSheet("color : rgb(200, 200, 200)")

lodingLbl.setText("STARTING PROGRAM")

lodingLbl.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)


splashLoadingLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
splashLoadingLayout.addStretch()
splashLoadingLayout.addWidget(lodingLbl)
splashLoadingLayout.addWidget(progressBar)
splashLoadingLayout.addStretch()
splashLoadingLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)

progressBar.setTextVisible(False)

splash.setLayout(splashLoadingLayout)

splash.setMask(splash_pix.mask())

splash.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I've figured it out. If the splash screen only rounds the corners of the widgets, then all I have to do is create ONE main Qwidget and set the splash screen to that. Then, I can set the background to transparent with `splash.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)`.

So, all I edited was:

```py
splashLoadingLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
splashLoadingLayout.addStretch()
splashLoadingLayout.addWidget(lodingLbl)
splashLoadingLayout.addWidget(progressBar)
splashLoadingLayout.addStretch()
splashLoadingLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)

progressBar.setTextVisible(False)

newWid = QtWidgets.QWidget()

newWid.setLayout(splashLoadingLayout)

splashPermLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
splashPermLayout.addWidget(newWid)

splash.setLayout(splashPermLayout)

splash.setMask(splash_pix.mask())

splash.show()
```

However, there would still be a border for the label. So, to disable that, I removed `border: 1px solid black` in the stylesheet to give me: `splash.setStyleSheet(u"border-radius: 33px;")`. This fixed everything

I hope this helps everyone else who also encounters this problem!